# jQuery: Run custom function 'if' if statement is false

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement

The custom function formdvalidate should run after else but it doesn't. How can I trigger it to run?
What I like to accomplish here is to check the text-fields of a form. If there are less then 3 characters its show the user some text. If the input is more then 3 it submits the form.

--I was thinking to wrong way, this works better.

```
$('#submit').click(formdvalidate);
```

The function

```
function formdvalidate(){
    $(".form-sel").each(function(){
        var n = $(this).closest('.contain-form').find('.custom:first').val().length;
        if ($('option:selected', this).val() === 'custom' && n < 3) {
            $(this).closest('.contain-form').find('.alert-short:first').show();
        }else{                          
            $('#poll').submit();
        }
    });                 
}
```

Comment: A `click` handler will _never_ get `true` as an argument.

Comment: I see. Didn't know that. Its seem like I have to change a lot more to make this code work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A function assigned as a click handler via `.click()` takes a jQuery event object as its first param--you named that param the same as your function
2. `formdvalidate === true` will never evaluate to true as `formdvalidate` is a function in the global scope, and a jQuery event object in the `click()` scope as per item 1
3. In your `formdvalidate` function, your return is inside of the `.each()` function, so `formdvalidate` never actually returns anything.

I'm not sure what you're really after or what your page looks like, but based on your comment to Slava Yanson, my best guess for you is below (although there are still things I am unsure of...)

```
$( '#submit' ).click( function( e )
{
  if( formdvalidate() === true) 
  {
    $( '#poll' ).submit();
  }

  e.preventDefault();
} );

function formdvalidate()
{
  var returnValue;

  $( '.form-sel' ).each( function()
  {
    var $containForm = $( this ).closest( '.contain-form' ),
        $alertShortFirst = $containForm.find( '.alert-short:first' ),
        n = $containForm.find( '.custom:first' ).val().length;
    if( $( 'option:selected', this ).val() === 'custom' && n < 3 )
    {
      $alertShortFirst.show();
      returnValue = false;
    }
    else
    {
      $alertShortFirst.hide();
      returnValue = true;
    }
  } );

  return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `formdvalidate` parameter is hiding the `formdvalidate` function.

Use better names.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
 if (formdvalidate() === true)  {
     $('#poll').submit();
        } else {        
             formdvalidate();
        }

});
```

I don't know if your logic will accomplish what you're trying to though.

Comment: Agreed--that would seem the most obvious edit, and yet we have no way of knowing if it is desired. Especially since it doesn't seem to make sense to run `formdvalidate` again after it failed.

Comment: @JAAulde "Especially since it doesn't seem to make sense to run formdvalidate again after it failed." exactly what I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

On line 2 of your code you are comparing an instance of your function to boolean. That won't validate. Can you provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: In essence the functions should show a text when the input is less then 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument "formvalidate" is shadowing your "formvalidate" function. Just rename your argument to something like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(do_validate) {
 if (do_validate === true)  {
     $('#poll').submit();
        } else {        
             formdvalidate();
        }
});
```

Comment: `do_validate` will never be `=== true` as it is a jQuery event object (first param to a click handling function which was assigned via `.click()`